# Trigger analysis for a Half Bridge Self oscillator

Tags: h-bridge

First of all, I'm sorry for bad English because I am not native. I am very interested to electronics self-oscillation.

I watched [a video in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ko4plGJTkY) about a self-oscillator Half-Bridge Converter and I captured its schematic blow. 2 questions:

1- If the DC-voltage current (created by 4 diodes and 22micro capacitor) passes T2 transformer, how does it can produce a AC-voltage current in T2 secondary?

2- How does the trigger section work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not self-oscillating. An exciter (DIAC) and feedback loop (TR2) are needed to maintain oscillation. The trigger is the DIAC, else it may not oscillate just by applying power. That is a very ancient circuit.

Comment: Perhaps the inverted dots on TR2 between T2 (base) and TH1 (collector) provide the positive feedback for oscillation and winding for base of T1 is complementary for a push-pull drive. C1/C2 filters the rectified AC and R3C3 with DIAC are self starting in Relaxation mode.

Comment: @  Tony Stewart. EE. According to its source, C1/C2 aren't for rectifying. Relaxation oscillation happens with combination of T1,T2, C1, C2 and TR2 as a feedback.

Comment: @AbbasMolaei - "*According to its source [...]*" Please edit your question to add a link to the source of that schematic / design. That will allow readers here to see information which is explained on the original webpage.

Comment: see http://www.cycloflow.com/2014/05/circuit-analysis-of-typical-electronic.html

Comment: @Abbas - Thanks, I've edited the question to add that link into the question for you, which is where it should be. I've also tidied-up some of the English to make it easier to read (since you've explained you're not a native speaker). Some parts I couldn't tidy up, as I wasn't sure what you actually intended, but I've made it a bit easier to read.

Comment: Hi @Abbas I just skimmed thru the article now. It seem to be written for amateur and shows no proof that it works.

Comment: @Tony Stewart. EE since '75. Thanks. I changed the question.

Comment: @Sparky256 Thanks. I changed the question.

Comment: I updated my answer ok ?

Comment: @ Tony Stewart. EE since '75. OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DIAC is a negative resistance clamp that form a relaxation oscillator to start from R 470k pull-up and 22nf. It is like a 2 pin SCR or unijunction and  goes into the base then the collector diode actually discharged the cap further once switched on briefly.

This creates a sawtooth  drive to get the oscillator started and pulse dump into the base .

> - 1) Assume input is 300Vdcand start current in 470k is
>     Ic=0.64 mA as 22nF charges up
>     C =22n and
>     dV is 32V for DIAC V_BO
>
>   Min Typ Max
>       28  32  36V
>     **dt** the time to trigger so from Ic=CdV/dt
>     dt= CdV/Ic=22n*32V/0.64m= 1.1ns assuming 1/2 cycle f= 1.8kHz
> - 2) when DIAC Vbo is reached voltage drops to 0.5V and current > 10mA with low negative resistance like an SCR latch.
>
>   - It will latch on until current drops below Ibo 100uA, which is less than above so voltage must be dropped further using Diode and transistor saturated by DIAC pulse.
> - 3) now the coil T1 10T is energized by lower NPN collector in series with T2 primary 88T  the other side of T2 is 300Vdc/2 with filter caps, lets assume now as an AC ground ( capacitance voltaqe divider for AC current.)
> - 4) This pulse duration depends on  T=RC decay time of 22nF and DIAC Rs
> - 5) the T1 magnetics  forms a blocking oscillator similar to a Joule Thief with T2 getting the AC square wave voltage and triangular current to step up current and step down voltage.
> - 6) as lower NPN-C goes low, upper E also and dot in 10T goes low as base in upper NPN coil dot goes high. as V=LdI/dt Vbe rises and then triggers while shutting off opposite dot direction on lower NPN.

Comment: @ Tony Stewart. EE since '75. Thanks. The problem is you're professional and I am very amateur. If you don't want to answer my question you may want introduce a website for amateurs. Anyway, I explain the process stage by stage and I'd like to help me if you want.  1- At a moment just after time=0 the red current moves from point 1 to point 2 and then charge 22n cap through 470k resistor. A branch of this current reaches to DIAC. The first question is: How does this red current can activate the DIAC (i.e its voltage reaches to V BO) while this current is DC voltage (Consonant Voltage) ?

Comment: When you charging the capacitor from the DC source via resistor the voltage across capacitor rise exponentially. And when the capacitor voltage reaches DIAC breakdown voltage the "blue" current will start to flow and this current will open lower NPN transistor.

Comment: @AbbasMolaei  is it clear now?

Comment: @ Tony Stewart. EE since '75. You are very kind and patient man and I have not seen this kind of people.Thanks again. Because I'm not native and a little amateur, the understanding of your answer is a little difficult for me, by the way I'm reading your answer and am very thankful to you.

Comment: @Tony Stewart. EE since '75. Exact and detailed answer. Thanks.